# Approach to solve SPOJ Cardtrick

Tags: algorithms

I am trying to solve the Problem [CTRICK](http://www.spoj.com/problems/CTRICK/) on SPOJ. I have an $O(n^2)$ solution that is giving “Time Limit Exceeded”. After browsing for some hints, I found that it can be solved using Interval Trees. But I have no idea, how to think it that way. Here is the problem:

The magician shuffles a small pack of cards, holds it face down and performs the
following procedure:

> 1. The top card is moved to the bottom of the pack. The new top card is dealt
>      face up onto the table. It is the Ace of Spades.
> 2. Two cards are moved one at a time from the top to the bottom. The next card is
>      dealt face up onto the table. It is the Two of Spades.
> 3. Three cards are moved one at a time…
> 4. This goes on until the $n$th and last card turns out to be the $n$ of Spades.
>
> This impressive trick works if the magician knows how to arrange the cards
>   beforehand (and knows how to give a false shuffle). Your program has to determine
>   the initial order of the cards for a given number of cards, $1 \le n \le 20000$.
>
> Input 1:
>
> ```
> 4
> ```
>
> Output 1:
>
> ```
> 2 1 4 3
> ```
>
> Input 2:
>
> ```
> 5
> ```
>
> Output 2:
>
> ```
> 3 1 4 5 2
> ```

Please suggest me some ideas.

Comment: "Please suggest me some ideas" is probably the most unspecific, open-ended "question" you could have come up with. You should narrow it down, maybe to approaches using interval trees? You can start the discussion off by stating why you think they could be a way to solve the problem more quickly.

Comment: Interesting problem, but not a question --> close.